# How to install mailparse in ubuntu 18 & PHP7.3

Tags: php

How to install mailparse in ubuntu 18 & PHP7.3 ?

error:  mailparse extension is currently in-active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install extension. How depends to your OS. On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install php-mailparse
```

Then, enable it (again Debian/Ubuntu and Apache2 Webserver assumed):

```
phpenmod mailparse
service apache2 reload
```